# copying a excel sheet to another or only deleting its rows using python

Tags: python, excel, copying

So I have this excel sheet with an enormous amout of data that I need to delete the first column and the first 7 rows, What I instantly thought of doing was something more or less like this

```
#Takes: start cell, end cell, and sheet you want to copy from.
def copyRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheet):
    rangeSelected = []
    #Loops through selected Rows
    for i in range(startRow,endRow + 1,1):
        #Appends the row to a RowSelected list
        rowSelected = []
        for j in range(startCol,endCol+1,1):
            rowSelected.append(sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value)
        #Adds the RowSelected List and nests inside the rangeSelected
        rangeSelected.append(rowSelected)

    return rangeSelected
```

but this implies that i know the amount of rows the sheet has, and since I am talking about a sheet that has an enourmous amount of data that is updated monthly I can never know for sure how many rows it has.

I literally only need to delete the first column and the first 7 rows how could I make it easier?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use range function. To answer your question in detail, it would be useful to know your framework for reading/writing to the sheet. In Python more general we prefer loops like this:

```
 c = someCollection()
 for element in c:
     do_something(element)
```

All frameworks I worked with allow this kind of syntax to iterate over cells, so yours probably too.

EDIT:

With Pandas it is very easy:

*Delete a column*:

```
del (table[column_index])
```

*Delete a row:*

```
table = table.drop(index=row_index)
```

Fully working example [here](https://gist.github.com/sherlockhomeless/80be5aff99d6d3933574ea012d8cec05)

Comment: i am usying spider 3.7
Also could you expand a little bit more your answer? I am farelly new at python so i did no quite know how to use this piece of code

Comment: What library or package do you use to read your excel file? Is it pandas?

Comment: I am useing openpyxl but if you have an easier way to do it with pandas i am alll ears

Comment: With pandas it is very easy. I tried using openpyxl, but I get a weird error with circular dependency. I added a working example to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
```

To drop a column / row by its label:

```
# Axis = 0 for rows and 1 for columns, by default set to 0
df.drop('column_name', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Or to drop by column number instead of column label, try this to delete, e.g. the 1st, 2nd and 4th columns

```
df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1, 3]], axis=1, inplace = True)  # df.columns is zero-based pd.Index
```

To drop by row number, e.g. the 1st, 3rd and 5th:

```
df.drop(df.index[[1, 3, 5]], inplace = True)
```